# How to rbind sublists in R

Tags: r, list, rbind

I have a list of lists of dataframes. What I am trying to do can be described by the following:

```
rbind(datalistpairs[[1]][[1]][[1]],datalistpairs[[1]][[2]][[1]],datalistpairs[[1]][[3]][[1]])
```

My sublist has j length so in reality I am trying something like (for j times):

```
rbind(datalistpairs[[1]][[1]][[1]],
datalistpairs[[1]][[2]][[1]],
datalistpairs[[1]][[3]][[1]],...,
datalistpairs[[1]][[j]][[1]])
```

What is the most efficient way to do it?

The output with three iterations creates an dataframe which looks like this:

```
      LAT    LON
   31  43.1818 5.2348
   311 43.1818 5.2348
   312 43.1818 5.2348
```

EDIT: I provide below sample data

```
datalistpairs = list(list(list(l1 = data.frame(LAT = 1, LON = 2), 
                               l2 = data.frame(LAT = 1, LON = 2)),
                          list(l1 = data.frame(LAT = 1, LON = 2), 
                               l2 = data.frame(LAT = 1, LON = 2))),
                     list(list(l1 = data.frame(LAT = 1, LON = 2), 
                               l2 = data.frame(LAT = 1, LON = 2)),
                         list(l1 = data.frame(LAT = 1, LON = 2), 
                              l2 = data.frame(LAT = 1, LON = 2))))
```

and my goal is to get:

```
rbind(datalistpairs[[1]][[1]][[1]],datalistpairs[[1]][[2]][[1]])
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/10068985) for us to test the output.

Comment: `t(sapply(datalistpairs[[1]], "[[", 1))`?

Comment: @DarrenTsai Sorry, I didn't mean to offend anyone with my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `map()` to extract the first element of each sublist.

```
library(purrr)

datalistpairs[[1]] %>% map_dfr(~ .[[1]])

#   LAT LON
# 1   1   2
# 2   1   2
```

---

The corresponding base R solution:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(datalistpairs[[1]], `[[`, 1))
```

---

***Edit:*** How to apply to `datalistpairs[[i]]` where i = 1, 2, 3, ..., n

```
lapply(1:n, function(i){
  do.call(rbind, lapply(datalistpairs[[i]], `[[`, 1))
})
```

Comment: Thank you Darren. Your solution is really elegant. To some extend how your solution can be best applied to datalistpairs[[i]] where i = 1, 2, 3, .... n? Same idea?

Comment: Amazing! Thank you.